# Effect of EC2 config change on EBS-backed Wordpress?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am deploying Wordpress site using LAMP AMI on EBS-backed EC2. Wordpress database will be stored in EBS.

Amazon keeps on updating base configuration of EC2 for better performance & security.

If I have to upgrade my EC2 then my EBS will get deleted.

How can I ensure that my EC2 gets updated without affecting my EBS?

EBS Snapshot is not of any help as new EC2 already has a EBS attached.

Do I have to always migrate my Wordpress site using backup & do this upgradtion?

Comment: *"Amazon keeps on updating base configuration of EC2 for better performance & security."*  What are you referring to, here?  The WordPress AMIs are not provided by Amazon.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon EC2 instances use EBS volumes as their disk volumes. They are populated from an Amazon Machine Image (AMI) when the instance is launched.

When AWS releases **updated AMIs**, any new instance launched from the AMI will contain the updated disk content. However, existing EC2 instances will not be changed (since they have a *copy* of the AMI at the time that the instance was launched).

You can also change the **Instance Type** of an EC2 instance, which gives it different hardware (CPU, Memory). This can be done by stopping the instance, changing the type and starting it again. This will **not** affect the contents of EBS volumes.

If you wish to keep your instance "current", simply run `sudo yum update` (Linux) or run the Windows Update utility to update your operating system and associated utilities rather than launching a whole new instance.